# What's the best practice of using JWT token for authentication?

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Currently, my Spring Boot project is consist of few REST services; resource service, authentication service, and so on.

The name of each service is self-descriptive but here are the roles,

- Resource service: responsible to manage all resources like User, Transaction, Supplier, and so on.
- Authentication server: responsible to create JWT access token upon a 'password' grant_type request

The framework does JWT token verification for me with the public key. Currently, the resource server processes any request if the requested JWT token is valid. However, I'm not sure what's the best practice and how to verify the requester owns the requested resource.

For example, if user Jacob wants to retrieve a transaction that Paul created with a valid JWT. My application somehow need to verify the requester, Jacob does not have ownership on Paul's transaction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice, I would say, is to keep your access tokens short-lived and keep them on the server side away from the user-agent and always use SSL on the wire.

JWT access tokens are bearer tokens. And as the name suggests, whoever's got them, can use them.

Think of an access token as a fiver (£5) and your Transaction Resource Server as a barman.

Now, let's say you drop your £5 on the floor.

It's my lucky day! I pick it up, go to the pub and buy a pint.

Does the barman ask me to whom the £5 note belongs?

No.

Just like your server doesn't care if it's Jacob or Paul with the token.

Comment: So what you're saying is, as long as the token is valid then a user can perform any actions? Hmmm... I can at least differentiate permissions based on roles and scope, am I right?

Comment: yes the scopes, subject / upn, audience, issuer and app ID etc... may be in the token. But anyone can still use that token. So if it is scoped to allow read access to Paul's recent transactions. Jacob can present the token and get access to Paul's recent transactions.

Comment: That makes sense. But can I ask one more question? If the API is OpenAPI which is for third-party API, using JWT token could cause a problem. Like AppCompany 1 uses their access token to query AppCompany 2's data. How can this be prevented?

Comment: Don't know much about OpenAPI but the audience `aud` value in a jwt access token can be used to limit the usage of a token to a particular resource API.

Comment: Can I use audience claim to verify if the requester has ownership on the requested resource? Spec says "If the principal
   processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the
   "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be
   rejected." So, assert the aud value is matching with the requested resource identifier.

Comment: the `aud` value relates to the API for which the authorisation server has created the access token for. The `aud` is a string array value so one token could be used by more than one API. The API receiving a token must check that it identifies itself amongst the `aud` values in the token otherwise it must reject the token. See [this link](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-tschofenig-oauth-audience-00.html)

Comment: @iandayman I got your point logically. But, what should be the value of token and how to manage it so that client and server both could handle and process request accordingly?

Answer (score -1):

I think the idea behind JWT token is that you can not determine from whom it is from token itself, you just check if the token is valid and you also check the timestamp.

Comment: In my JWT token, I do have 'user_name', 'authorities' and 'scope' fields. Can I use them for ownership verification? Like... have a filter which intercepts the request, extract the access token, decrypt it then matches these three fields to verify the ownership.